# How to migrate data from Parse to Amazon Simple DB

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-simpledb

i'm trying to migrate my database from Parse to Amazon Simple DB. I've exported data from Parse.

Right now, i've JSON file for every Parse' table. I'm not sure how to import it on Simple DB. **How to migrate data from Parse to Simple DB?**.

**Note:** I did all this migration activity for Firebase, and converted my JSON files into **one file**, that was imported on Firebase. I am looking for some solution like that.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @GeorgeMWhitaker, the question is, How to migrate database from Parse to SimpleDB? manually or via some script?
By manual, i don't mean to add all the data again (row by row)